# How can I save an image from a website using python, using their Canvas ID and not a URL

Tags: python, image, canvas, save, generative-adversarial-network

Specifically from this GauGAN2 demo:
http://gaugan.org/gaugan2/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udYM6.png)

I know a few methods to use Screenshot, but I'm tried of using screenshot haha, it creates too many problems for me.

I tried using "ActionChains" but once the right click menu pops up it won't send any input to there, probably because it's a windows GUI and not part of chrome (using chrome driver / selenium by the way)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/APb5AVis
This is my temporary solution, pixel detection and moving the files so that I can just process the ones i need to process (which for me will be with photoshop scripts, so that I can retain the file name)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.